# Reading JSON file from dropbox iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing, dropbox

I have a scenario where app reads file from server (dropbox) and checks version. If new version is available then download the app.

I'm trying to read file from [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/22mm417fxdqdn8c/FileStructure.txt?dl=0) but getting `null` after JSON parsing.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/22mm417fxdqdn8c/FileStructure.txt?dl=0"] 
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                       error:&error];

if(!error) {  //Handle error
    // NSLog(@"strFileContent: %@",strFileContent);
    NSData *data = [strFileContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"json : %@",[json description]);
}
else
    NSLog(@"Error in reading!");
}
```

Any alternative to DropBox?

Comment: try this https://www.dropbox.com/s/22mm417fxdqdn8c/FileStructure.txt?dl=1

Comment: @HarvantS. What does dl=0 and dl=1 signify?

Comment: dl=1 will download file. dl=0 will load file in dropbox consol.

Comment: Do **not** ignore the error parameter, in this case on the `NSJSONSerialization` statement. It provided the following: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." Error parameters are your friends.

Comment: For reference, the dl parameter is documented here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a text file containing JSON; it's an RTF file containing JSON.  That won't work with `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1347\cocoasubrtf570
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 \{\
  "Version": 1.0,\
  "ImageList": [\
    "Nature.png",\
    "Nature-1.png",\
    "Ballon.png"\
  ]\
\}}
```

You've saved that file using an editor that uses RTF (the default Mac `TextEdit` ). you'll need to re-save as plain text.

Provided URL is incorrect too. If you need only file contents you have to set dl=1 (last component of url). Like so -

[dropbox.com/s/22mm417fxdqdn8c/FileStructure.txt?dl=1](http://dropbox.com/s/22mm417fxdqdn8c/FileStructure.txt?dl=1)

Comment: @HarvantS. So renaming a file changes its contents?

Comment: Earlier file was in .RTF format then changed to .txt format.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Nope; still seeing RTF here.

Comment: @HarvantS. No, changing file extensions won't help.  The file needs to be recreated using a text editor that saves in text format, not RTF format.

Comment: yes changing file extension wont work here. He has to create a new txt file or a json file (could use plist for that).

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, I find it quite ugly, but still.
First issue, as mentioned by other: `yourURLEtcdl=1`.
Second big issue, the file is a rtf file, not a JSON object.
So, since there is a way going with RTF => NSAttributedString => NSString => "JSON" => Get your wanted value, here is what you could do:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/22mm417fxdqdn8c/FileStructure.txt?dl=1"];
NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                       error:&error];

NSLog(@"strFileContent: %@", strFileContent);

if(!error)
{
    NSError *rtfError;
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[strFileContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                               options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                 error:&rtfError];
    if (rtfError)
    {
        NSLog(@"RTFError: %@", [rtfError localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"string: %@", [attributedString string]);

        NSData *data = [[attributedString string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
        if (jsonError)
        {
            NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [jsonError localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonDict);
            NSInteger version = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Version"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"Version: %ld", (long)version);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

As I said, I don't find these very great, it works, but this solution seems to me quite messy (passing twice with `NSData`).